# Github, how to debug "failed to refresh the working directory"

Tags: heroku, github, github-for-windows

I am using the newest GitHub for windows, and this occasionally happen
always suggesting I debug the repo in shell.
I am looking to learn how to do this debug
Is there any source that explains all (or even most) common problems that would cause this?
The repo seems ok when used from command line.

The specific case that is driving me crazy now is a Heroku project I'm trying to work on with a friend who uses Mac. Not sure if that is related, and I want to learn how to debug the general case, but any tips here would be useful as well

Comment: git status is a big help, and the mac PC issue is the based on the Icon^m^m file
I still think this question is important since searching this error on Google/Bing/Here shows nothing, and I'd still like to see a list of possible causes.
http://blog.bitfluent.com/post/173740409/ignoring-icon-in-gitignore

Answer (score 1):

Running GitHub with administrator rights resolved the problem as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the "GitHub for Windows" log in

```
# WinXp:
C:\Documents and Settings\LoginName\Local Settings\Application Data\GitHub
# Or Win7:
C:\Users\LoginName\Local Settings\Application Data\GitHub
```

I have seen this message:

- on authentication problem (I used it in a corporate environment)
- when Windows keep an handle on some resources which should be updated by the `git pull`.

I usually keep a bash opened (launched from the "GitHub from Windows" GUI) in order to repeat the failed GUI operation as a git command.